# How to bypass Linux VFS inode cache? Is it safe not to add inode to its super_block list?

Tags: c, linux, filesystems, operating-system, linux-kernel

Since our file system implementation stores inode just in memory, so we do not want to waste more for inode cache.

Under VFS, we plan not to add new inode to the inode cache hash talbe, and not to add it to the super_block inode list. But I am not sure whether it is safe to do so? Will VFS meet problems when it uses them anywhere else?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at tmpfs, which also just stores things in memory, and which must have had the thought at some point.

Answer (score 1):

You can not add things to the inode cache, but you need to handle the VFS hooks for most things and direct them to your in-memory version rather than the cached list.

Look through the VFS generic defaults, identify which ones use the cache, and override them. This should work.

You can also look at the source-code for ramfs.